# Copy Row From One Sheet to Another if Marked with "X" in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I do purchasing for my company and have been working on a spreadsheet (Excel 2003) to help people order things. I have two worksheets, Items and Orders. I would like the user to be able to type a quantity into the cell specified and have that row of information copied over to the orders sheet.

For example, If I type 500 into cell A3 in the Items sheet, cells A3-F3 would be copied over to the Orders sheet in the first available row (happens to be A2 right now). If the next item being ordered is on A9, they would type the quantity into A9 of the Items sheet and it would copy A9-F9 to A3-F3 of the Orders sheet and so on. After the different rows are copied over, they would be able to copy the grouped up rows into an email and send it.

So, any number typed into Column A of the Items Sheet will copy A-F over to the first available row in the Orders sheet. Let me know if I left something out. Sorry if this is a dumb question but I have spent a good 5 hours and can't seem to figure this one out.

Thanks!

Comment: You are supposed to try yourself and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place this code in Items worksheet code pane:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        With Worksheets("Orders")
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 6).Value = Target.Resize(, 6).Value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It copied over what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Without using any macros, you could set up the sheet like this:
Make the entire first worksheet into a table (select it, and then click 'Insert'>'Table'). Have the user enter the amounts needed, then filter the table by 'Quantity' and do not include 0. Then you can copy and paste the order into an email! You don't even need the second worksheet.

[image: step by step: creating a table]